# TSQL Replicate row n times based on data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given a table with fields Id, Qty, Code and a row in the table with the data

```
Id   Qty   Code
1    3     A,B,C
```

I would like to change this in the database to be

```
Id   Qty  Code
1    1    A 
2    1    B
3    1    C
```

Is there an easy TSQL to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create Split Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]  
    (  
      @delimited NVARCHAR(MAX),  
      @delimiter NVARCHAR(100)  
    )   
 RETURNS @t TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), val NVARCHAR(MAX))  
AS  
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @xml XML  
  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@delimited,@delimiter,'</t><t>') + '</t>'  

  INSERT INTO @t(val)  
  SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item  
  FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)  
  RETURN  
END
```

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Id INT, Qty INT,  Code VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (1, 3 , 'A,B,C'), (2, 4 , 'E,F,G,H,H')
```

### Query

```
SELECT t.Id 
      ,COUNT(*) AS QTY 
      ,c.val AS Code
FROM @TABLE t CROSS APPLY dbo.split(t.Code, ',')c
GROUP BY t.Id ,c.val
```

### Result

```
╔════╦═════╦══════╗
║ Id ║ QTY ║ Code ║
╠════╬═════╬══════╣
║  1 ║   1 ║ A    ║
║  1 ║   1 ║ B    ║
║  1 ║   1 ║ C    ║
║  2 ║   1 ║ E    ║
║  2 ║   1 ║ F    ║
║  2 ║   1 ║ G    ║
║  2 ║   2 ║ H    ║
╚════╩═════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Thanks, did it pretty similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a custom table values Split function. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DelimitedString NVARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @DelimString = Code FROM tableName

SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitEx(@DelimString, ',')


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitEx]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Qty' = 1,
        'Code' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a bug and fix it.

now it works perfect -:)

```
--create table #t(id int,qty int,code varchar(10))
declare @x varchar='1'

declare @str varchar(10)='A,B,C'
declare @i int =(select qty from tbl1)
declare @sql varchar(max)

while  @i !=0
begin
set @sql='insert into  #t  
SELECT '+@x+' ,1,(substring('''+@str+''',-1+2*+'+@X+',1))'
EXEC (@sql)
set  @i = @i -1
set  @x = @x +1
end
select * from #t
--truncate table #t
```